# opening files using python / IDLE returns "no such file or directory" for pathname

Tags: python, file-io, python-idle

I have WORDS_TXT = /macintosh HD/users/[username]/Desktop/[file]/words.txt/

but when run, python says "no such file or directory", however going though finder and "go to folder" that exact pathname brings me to the file I am trying to open. I am running python 3.2 on a macbook pro with Mac OS X 10.7

thank you in advance

Comment: It may be as simple as removing the trailing / on your variable.  Please post more code.

Comment: How can I define the right pathname that python will understand and be able to call on?

Comment: WORDS_TXT = "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt/" and my words are saved in words.txt I call for the file with open(WORDS_TXT, "r", 0) for read only. this is an assignment on MIT open course ware (problem set 5 (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/ps5.py) thank you

Comment: It still looks like you have a trailing slash on your file name.  `words.txt/` is not the same as `words.txt`.

Comment: WORDS_TXT = "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt"

inFile = open(WORDS_TXT, 'r', 0)

returns:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/ps5.py", line 241, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt'

Comment: Am I missing something here? This seems as though it's the easiest most insignificant part of the code (I didn't even write it, it was provided) yet I cannot continue through the problem without this file.

Answer (score 1):

```
WORDS_TXT = '/macintosh HD/users/[username]/Desktop/[file]/words.txt/'
WORDS_TXT.rstrip('/')
```

Comment: sorry, I have the quotations on my coding, that's not the problem. I posted my exact coding above, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the filename was read from another file, there's a chance that you have an end of line character or whitespace at the end of the string. You should remove this plus the extraneous '/' at the end of the filename.

```
WORDS_TXT = WORDS_TXT.rstrip(' \r\n/')
```

Comment: WORDS_TXT = "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/words.txt"

copied and pasted right from my code... Is there really a problem with this? I cannot think of anything and everything you all suggest (you all are a lot more qualified than I am with this) does not work...

thanks for all of your help so far though, I just haven't solved it as of yet... I posted the source for the code in comments above and the error it returns in IDLE

Comment: Since nobody has been able to figure this out based on what you've told us, I have to conclude the answer lies in something you haven't told us yet.

Comment: I have to agree with you. Here is the code:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/ps5.py

the only part we need to worry about is defining the file. I saved words.txt in a file on my desktop titled ComputerScienceProblemSets (no spaces). When I run:

WORDS_TXT = "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt"

and:

infile = open(WORDS_TXT, "r", 0) 

it returns (in IDLE) 'No such file or directory: '

Comment: I changed both parts to WORDS_TXT earlier on when I was re-writing the code. It is no longer WORDLIST_FILENAME

Comment: @Braiden, one last thing: go to a terminal window and execute the command `ls -l "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt"` and give us the results. Please be aware that the filename is case sensitive; if you've substituted an upper case letter for a lower case one, the file won't open.

Comment: Last login: Wed Jul 20 18:15:40 on console
Braiden-Besseys-MacBook-Pro:~ Btbessaay$ Braiden-Besseys-MacBook-Pro:~ Btbessaay$ ls -l "/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt"
ls: /Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt: No such file or directory
..........

But how does that make sense when I type the pathname in Finder and it takes me right to the folder?

Comment: @Braiden, do the `ls` command a few more times with parts on the right taken off. I'm sure the answer will present itself.

Comment: ok... well, I did the 'Go to folder' through finder, starting with Macintosh HD, it took me there, and then users, it took me there and so on. I then did the same on terminal and it worked. The pathname is still THE EXACT SAME. It returns a blank line, I'm assuming that means it found it? Yet, it still does not work in python...

Comment: @Braiden, I'm not a Mac user so I'm not familiar with how the finder shows the path. I do know that `ls` tells the true story, so please try to rely on it rather than the finder.

Comment: what should ls return if the pathname is correct? I got a blank line, and then without changing anything, I tried it in python (exact same pathname as in terminal) and it didn't work. I tried it again in the terminal and it had gone back to 'No such file or directory'

Comment: @Braiden, if the path is an empty directory you'll get the blank line; otherwise it should either give you a list of files if it was a directory, a single line if it was an existing file, and "No such file or directory" otherwise.

Comment: OK, so I type ls only and it returns a list of folders in my user file (Btbessaay stated above) How can I use that to start from there? What is the correct syntax for ls on terminal. ls '<pathname>' ??

Comment: @Braiden: `ls -l 'pathname'` If you leave off the pathname it will list everything in your current directory; in this case that's not useful because you're trying to test the full path to the file.

Comment: Braiden-Besseys-MacBook-Pro:~ Btbessaay$ ls -l '/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt'
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Btbessaay  staff  648783 Jul 21 15:29 /Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt

how is this? pathname still does not work in python

Comment: @Braiden, that's perfect. Now copy and paste that exact string into your program - that will eliminate any upper-case/lower-case substitutions.

Comment: Terminal finds the document (words.txt) with /Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt

yeat python does not, calls for complete pathname. Adding Macintosh HD to the beginning (complete pathname) simply says my document does not exist...

Comment: I copy it exactly and get 'Cannot have unbuffered text in I/O'... This is honestly getting ridiculous, I really apologize for being difficult and I thank you for all of your help. Just nothing I do will work. I'm very new to this sort of stuff (coding with python/coding at all). Any other thoughts? Maybe python is having trouble with the new mac operating system?

Comment: @Braiden, the terminal and Python should react identically. There's still something you're not telling us. What do you mean by "calls for complete pathname"?

Comment: @Braiden, now with the complete error message it becomes clear. You're using the third parameter in the `open` call - leave it off.

Comment: well what do you know... it was their code that was wrong... what in the world was that third parameter there for? they specifically said "you do not need to understand this code"... Well that was a learning experience... Thank you for all of your help!!!

Comment: @Braiden, an upvote would be a nice thank-you. And for the future, be sure to include the **exact error message** - it's relevant!

Answer (score 0):

Rest assured, python has no limitation in this regard. About the only two possibilities are:

1. There is a hard-to-see typo in your code so you are looking for the wrong file, or
2. The code is correct and the file really doesn't exist because there is a hard-to-see typo in the actual file name. For example, maybe the file on disk has a leading or trailing space in the name.

Comment: The typo idea makes perfect sense, but when I try 'Go to Folder' through finder and type '/Macintosh HD/Users/Btbessaay/Desktop/ComputerScienceProblemSets/words.txt' exactly, shouldn't that show an error if there is a typo? All I do from there is copy and paste into my code...

Comment: @Braiden Bessey: I'm not sure what to tell you. Thousands of python programs have proven that if the file is there, `open` will open it. Open up a terminal. Type `ls '<paste your path here>'` and see what it says. If it finds your file, *paste* that exact string into your python code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WORDS_TXT = '\macintosh HD\users/[username]\Desktop/[file]\words.txt\'
```